# stop to redirect on customer/account/login/ magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, login, redirect

When I am opening this `http://websitedomain.com/` domain name, then it directly       redirects to this link `http://websitedomain.com/customer/account/login/` but I want that  it redirect on **websitedomain.com/** only.

Answer (score 0):

There might be third party module for redirect the visitors on login page.To disable it go to `app/etc/modules` and disable all third party modules one by one.Once you will find right module just disable that module.Make sure before doing it disable the cache.